# Why is the hazard function linked to the PDF

Tags: probability

Why is the hazard function, defined as such:

$$h(t) = \lim_{\delta t\downarrow 0} \frac{P(t \le T < t+\delta t\mid T\ge t)}{\delta t}.$$

equal to the (derivative of F(t)) divided by (1 - F(t)) where F(t) is the probability density function.

I've seen this here: https://faculty.washington.edu/yenchic/18W_425/Lec5_survival.pdf and they don't give a proof as to why it's true.

Comment: This is the *definition* of the hazard function. Better to ask for a *motivation* which is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Failure_rate#hazard_function) for the exponential failure distribution.

Comment: Not really, it was the Bayes Theorem (cf. answer). The first equality is the definition, not the second equality ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is Bayes Theorem,

P(t≤T<t+δt∣T≥t) = P(t≤T<t+δt and  T≥t) / P(T≥t ; no failure within t )

```
            = { F(t+ δt ) - F(t) } / [1- F(t) ]
```

h(t) = lim   { [ F(t+ δt ) - F(t) ] /δt }/ [1- F(t) ] = dF(t)/dt / [ 1-F(t)]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).